# iOS 7 : Call method from subclassed UIAlertView

Tags: objective-c, ios7, subclass, uialertview

I've created a subclass of UIAlertView inside which I override following method:

```
- (void)dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

The problem is this method is not invoked though I tap any of the buttons on alert view. What might be the problem? Has iOS 7 disallowed subclassing UIAlertView? Plese help.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by subclassing `UIAlertView`?

Comment: I've added a custom view having a couple of textfields to alert view.  There are two buttons on alert view: Submit and Cancel. On tapping 'Submit' I don't want alert view to be dismissed if user has entered wrong input.

Comment: Have you looked into [`alertViewStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIAlertView/alertViewStyle). `UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput` and `alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:` delegate method should be able to make this happen for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subclassing UIAlertView has never been supported.

[UIAlertView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html)

> #### Subclassing Notes
>
> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

Answer (score 0):

From [UIAlertView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html):

```
The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.
```